# Given is a set of clauses. Find a logic formula in CNF such that..

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

> Given is the set of clauses $$\tau_1 := \left\{\left\{P, \neg
> S\right\}, \left\{S\right\},\left\{S,R\right\},\left\{\neg S, \neg
> P\right\}\right\}$$
>
> For this set of clauses, find a logic formula $\varphi_1$ in CNF such
>   that for all interpretations $I$ you have that $$I \models \varphi_1
> \Leftrightarrow I \models  \tau_1$$

I start with change the set of clauses to CNF formula.

How?

In reading they say example:

> The CNF formula $$\varphi = A_1 \wedge (\neg A_2 \vee A_1) \wedge (A_3
> > \vee \neg A_2 \vee \neg A_1)$$
>
> is represented by the finite set of clauses
>   $$\left\{\left\{A_1\right\}, \left\{\neg A_2, A_1\right\}, \left\{A_3,
> > \neg A_2, \neg A_1\right\}\right\}$$

So in this case the formula is:
$$\varphi_1 := (P \vee \neg S) \wedge (S) \wedge (S \vee R) \wedge (\neg S \vee \neg P)$$

But I don't know it also satisfy the condition in task? I mean $$I \models \varphi_1 \Leftrightarrow I \models \tau_1$$

Comment: What does $I\vDash \tau_1$ even mean? Do you have a separate definition of the meaning of something on that form?

Comment: Yes, your approach and solution is correct. The task just asks for a CNF which is equivalent to the clauses. And two statements are equivalent if they are truthy for exactly the same interpretations, which is exactly what $I \models \varphi_1 \Leftrightarrow I \models \tau_1$ states